# Odroid N2 "getGpioList()" returns empty array, can't access gpio ports

Tags: java, android, gpio, android-things, odroid

Im running Lineage 16.0 on the Odroid N2.
I want to access the GPIO pins via an Android App and have found something interesting inside the Android-Things documentary.

https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio

Now my problem is, my app doen't find any gpio ports. 
The following code only returns an empty array:

```
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
List<String> portList = manager.getGpioList();
```

Of course permissions are set as following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
```

I then just ignored that and tried to connect to the GPIO ports with this code:

```
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
Gpio gpio = manager.openGpio("488");
```

But still no success. but I'm not exactly sure if it doesn't work because instead "488" isn't the correct name for the GPIO-port or because of something else. I've also tried some variations like "BCM12" etc.

In either case, I'd like to get "getGpioList()" working first, but I honestly can't find the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Things didn't support Odroid N2 hardware platform. All Android Things supported hardware described in [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms).

Answer (score 3):

Please check reference android image supported by the Hardkernel.
Physical Pin number is pin name, like pin #7's pin name is just a "7".
Like below! :)

```java
PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
Gpio gpio = manager.openGpio("7");
```

Comment: Hi @sang Chul Go. Thanks for your answer. It would probably help the person who asked if you could provide a code snippet that corrects the erroneous code (I assume it's the openGpio() call...)